# Dom parsing and javascript execution

Tags: javascript, dom

```
<script src="mmm.js"></script>
<style>
 #box{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:red;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="box"></div>
</body>
```

and the mmm.js file

```
$('#box').css("background-color","black");
```

Why the above code works? The following code does not work:

```
<script>
  $('#box').css("background-color","black");
</script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

and this is rational  since `box` is not known to the script. How `box` is known to the external script since it is placed above `body` and is executed before `<div id="box"></div>` is parsed?

Comment: I think the page is loaded fully before getting the external js. Not the case in your second situation.

Comment: "Why the above code works? " — It … doesn't. Here is [a live demo](http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/36861279/) (I added jQuery, which you forgot to include in your test case), if the code worked the square would be black not red.

Comment: If that's the complete contents of `mmm.js` then it doesn't work.  I suspect you've not given us all the facts and there's a document ready handler in that file.

Comment: where is jQuery defined?

Comment: @Quentin: i was wondering if the split-open <head> could quirk it out somehow, thanks for making a good test with real files, not possible in fiddle et al.

Answer (score -2):

I tried your code and it doesn't work either way to me. Either way the box does not change background.

What you ought to do is make sure the page has been fully loaded before switching the background to black:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
     $('#box').css("background-color","black");
});
```

You can place this in a .js file or inside your HTML.

Comment: "When you put the javascript code in a file and call it from your HTML the browser first loads the HTML." — `<script>` elements, even ones with external `src`s, block parsing of the DOM (unless they are deferred or async, which this one is not)

Comment: You are right, the first code doesn't work either and I was just guessing.